# Inequality for complex exponential function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, exponential-function

It is easy to proof that for $x \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
\mid e^{ix} \mid =1
$$
But my lecture notes also contains this: For $x,u \in \mathbb{R}^d$
$$
\mid e^{i<x,u>}\mid\leq 1
$$
How do I show that?

Comment: $<x,u>\in\mathbb R$ is the scalar product

Answer (score 1):

$\langle x, u \rangle$ is a real number. Hence $|e^{i\langle x, u \rangle}|=1$, in fact.

Comment: Yes, that's what I tought too. I mean $\leq$ is not wrong then but still weird...